# Refresh jQuery DataTable from DOM - NO AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an HTML table that is completely prepopulated by the server; there is no AJAX anywhere on the page.

I have javascript code that lets me move rows between this table and another one (which starts out empty).

The data set is small enough that there's no need for Ajax pagination, but large enough that the sorting/filtering stuff in DataTable is useful.  So I turned the first table into a a DataTable.

Problem: rows I move to the second table are still affected by the data table code after I move them; any new searching or sorting or filtering on the first table empties the second table.

So what I'd like to be able to do is modify the table underlying the DataTable and then refresh it - have it re-analyze the table as it exists in the DOM and rebuild its state from that.  Preferably without losing its current search string, sort order, etc.

I tried using the DataTable API to remove and add rows, but it didn't help - even after removing and redrawing, a search for the content of the removed row causes it to reappear.

Any help appreciated.

Here's the original row-moving code:

```
var top    = $('#top');
var bottom = $('#bottom');
$('body').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function(ev) {
  var box = $(ev.currentTarget);
  var tr = box.closest('tr');
  var table = tr.closest('table');

  var to;
  if (table.attr('id') == 'top' && checkbox.checked) {
    to = bottom;
  } else {
    to = top;
  }
  to.append(tr);
});
```

Ok, I was able to get it working using the DataTable API.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insight into your row-moving code would be helpful to answer you correctly. Perhaps you need to use $.clone() and $.remove() for moving rows - that should clear the rows from any attached events.

Alternatively, you could .destroy() your Datatable (see http://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()), move the row then initialize it again

[Edit:]
Yes you need to use the Datatable API to move rows.

That library seems to support it nicely: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html + http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()

Comment: See edit.  If I destroy the datatable, I'll lose the search/sort/filter state.

Comment: What’s the benefit of not using Ajax? I heard using destroy is not preferred. Though this is obviously the correct answer.

Comment: There isn't. OP requested no Ajax.